# Is it possible to estimate the time of defragmentation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, defragment

My PC is 8% fragmented, and I'm currently on Pass6, more or less 20 minutes have passed.
I wonder if there is a way to know the estimated time it will finish?

Comment: no, it depends on various factors like the moving strategy, drive speed and the amount of data to move

Comment: 8% fragmentation is nothing - no defragmentation needed at all. Except the case when filesystem metafiles are fragmented - but OS defragmenter cannot process them. I'd recommend you to use third-party defragmenters - for example, Piriform Defraggler... they can use different defrag strategies/types, predict defrag time, defrag metafiles, show the defrag process, use sheduling, etc.

Comment: It is hard to estimate.It is depend on the files fragmentation and size. You can left it do this and have a rest . Set a schedule of turn off PC after defrag.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i assume you are using HDD,if it is SSD, **you should NOT do defrag**. It only make SSD's lifespan shortened.

Fragmentation occurs when the file system cannot or will not allocate enough contiguous space to store a complete file as a unit, but instead puts parts of it in gaps between existing files (usually those gaps exist because they formerly held a file that the file system has subsequently deleted or because the file system allocated excess space for the file in the first place). Files that are often appended to (as with log files) as well as the frequent adding and deleting of files (as with emails and web browser cache), larger files (as with videos) and greater numbers of files contribute to fragmentation and consequent performance loss.

Disk Defragmenter might take from several minutes to a few hours to finish, depending on the size and degree of fragmentation of your hard disk. You can still use your computer during the defragmentation process.